# ¿Como usar un TextBox para distintas operaciones SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Estoy utilizando WebForms, por la plataforma que ya se encuentra trabajando correctamente en el trabajo, en conjunto con VB.NET, tengo una duda en como poder trabajar con un solo campo de texto, y, que a su vez, el mismo campo de texto pueda funcionar para almacenar información distinta en la base de datos.

Tengo mi tabla de SQL Server como la siguiente

```
CREATE TABLE TblUser(
    UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserName varchar(50),
    UserLastName varchar(50),
    UserAge INT,
    UserPhone varchar(50),
    UserEmail varchar(50),
    UserCreated_at DateTime,
    UserUpdated_at DateTime 
)
```

La idea principal, es poder utilizar un solo campo de texto para todos los campos.
Se puede utilizar un array unidimensional y así, después de llenar el array proceder a guardar la información en la Base de Datos.

En la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué es lo que va a hacer?

En el Label "Ingrese nombre: ", va a guardar el nombre del usuario, enseguida el Label va a aparecer "Ingrese Apellidos: " y el TextBox va a permitir guardar el Apellido, y va a ser sucesivamente.

Solo, que no se como realizar las operaciones para lograr el resultado esperado.

Aquí esta el código de VB.NET

**Frontend**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblChange" runat="server" Text="Ingrese nombre:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtChange" runat="server" Width="190px"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Backend**

```
Imports System.Data
Partial Class userRegister
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        txtChange.Focus()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub txtChange_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtChange.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Quieres que el mismo textbox guarde todos los datos en tu tabla?, cada que termines de escribir un campo y presiones un botón el label va a cambiar para pedirte el siguiente campo dentro del mismo textbox?

Comment: Así es, o al momento de presionar la tecla enter... Al momento de que se realice la acción, pueda el usuario ingresar más valores, y se registren en las columnas correspondientes...

Answer (score 0):

Esto no creo que solucione tu problema pero no creo que puedas hacerlo de esa manera, yo e hecho algo parecido pero se la longitud exacta que necesito, sin embargo los nombres y apellidos no tienen una longitud definida, creo que seria mejor hacer un formulario con muchos TextBox o hacerlo con MsgBox

---

Perdón se me ocurrió una manera pero tendrás que usar un botón, puedes almacenar el estado de lo que esta haciendo y de ahí ver que acción se ejecutara

Ejemplo (pseudocodigo):

```
variable estado = "nombre" (string)
if(estado == "nombre") {
   label.text = "nombre"
}else if(estado == "apellidos"){
  label.text = "apellidos"
}
```

tendrás que cambiar el valor de "estado" cuando presione el boton si presiona el botón y el estado es "nombre" que el estado cambie a "apellidos", si no entiendes dime y puedo hacer un ejemplo mas explicado.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por que no creas todo el objeto de tu tabla y luego juegas con el atributo "visible"?

pones dos botones "Atrás" y "siguiente":
y en los eventos de los botones y ajustas

`MyControl.Style["Visibility"] = "visible";`

También puedes crear un combobox con los nombres de los campos de la tabla e ir ingresando la información respectiva en el textbox.

Pero mejor crea todos los controles necesarios para guardar la información.

Saludos